# Confused about python versions

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am incorporating a package (py_trees for behavior trees) in my ROS program. Unfortunately,  py_trees does not support python2. I am using ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 from what I can tell, ROS python source file often require python2.

My question is: How do I set ROS up to allow me to call a Pythion 3 only package?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366400/confused-about-python-versions/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-11-25**:
This doesn't seem to be a "ROS" question as much as a python2 and python3 compatibility question. You might find better resources under that premise.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-11-25**:
@stevemacenski - I didn't explain it well the first time; can you take a look again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Officially, Melodic does not support Python 3. So the official answer would be: you can't.

There are ways to build just enough of Melodic with Python 3 to do this though, and an alternative could be using something like `catkin_virtualenv`, which does support Python 3.

However, I'm confused: [py_trees_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/py_trees_ros) supports ROS Melodic (it has even been released there). Could you not use that?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-11-26**:
I built my code outside of ROS with py_trees. Never looked closely at py_trees_ros but it looks like its a slightly different API. Anyway your answer is what I requirer - melodic doesn't support py3 directly. I will look at py_trees_ros, and I assume that will solve my problem. If you promote your comment to an answer I will check it off.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-11-26**:
What about this: https://medium.com/@beta_b0t/how-to-setup-ros-with-python-3-44a69ca36674 instructions for writing nodes in py3 on melodic?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-26**:
As I wrote, it's all possible. Just depends on how complicated you want to make things for yourself.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-27**:
If you absolutely don't want to use `py_trees_ros` I would actually recommend to look a `catkin_virtualenv` instead of building Melodic with Python 3. `catkin_virtualenv` supports Python 3 "natively".